# C# Add an element to a each position in a collection object

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, filter, filehelpers

My goal is to write values to a preexisting .csv file stored in a collection.  Currently, I am reading the values stored in the .csv file and storing them in a collection using the filerhelper library.  But I want to add 4 column fields {Product ,Base Price,Ship Price,Total Price}, then, if the customer name in my `records` collection matches the customer name in `customerandproducts` collection - write in the corresponding data from `customerandproducts` collection to the 4 fields I added.

Here's a simplified version of my source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FileHelpers;

namespace ReadFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Orders>();
            var records = engine.ReadFile("Daniel.csv");

            // var customersandproducts = addresses.Select(x => new { x.Name, x.AddressLine1, x.AddressLine2, x.City, x.State, x.S_OrderId, x.PostalCode })
            // .Join(products, custs => custs.S_OrderId, prod => prod.P_OrderId,(custs, prod) => new { custs.Name, custs.AddressLine1, custs.AddressLine2, custs.City, custs.State, custs.PostalCode, prod.Title, prod.Quantity, prod.ItemPrice, prod.ShippingPrice });

            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(record.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(record.Track);
                Console.WriteLine(record.Price);
            }
        }
    }

    [DelimitedRecord(",")]
    public class Orders
    {
        public string Name;

        public string Track;

        public string Price;
    }
}
```

Here is the data in my .csv file:

`ShipToCompanyorName,PackageTrackingNumber,ShipmentInformationTotalShipmentReferenceCharge
customer1,1Z620Y1V0347293915,12.6
customer2,1Z620Y1V0347106126,9.18
customer3,1Z620Y1V0347584931,13.63
customer4,1Z620Y1V0346366348,11.37
customer5,1Z620Y1V0348472309,31.
customer6,1Z620Y1V0348325290,31.34`

My Problem:  I want to add {Product ,Base Price,Ship Price,Total Price} into the first row of the .csv file, then fill in each column with information in `customerandproducts` collection using the customer name as the key.

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: What does the record object look like?

Comment: So, each row in the .csv is one item in the `Collection<>`?  How do you separate the elements in the .csv?  Are you using `string[] args`?  If so, that seems a bit rudimentary.  Try making a class for what you want the data to look like, then serialize/deserialize to/from the .csv.

Comment: I am not using `string[] args` and, yes, each row is one item in the `Collection<>`.  But I just want to pull specific information within the `customerandproducts` collection and add this info to the correct row, under the correct field - i.e.  {Product ,Base Price,Ship Price,Total Price}.

Comment: A **picture** of your .csv file? Why not just copy/paste the data itself so that others can use it?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan,  done

Answer (score 1):

You can use two classes and later map them with [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started)

```
namespace ReadFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Orders>();
            var records = engine.ReadFile("Daniel.csv");
            var mapped = Mapper.Map<Orders[], MoreFields[]>(records );
            // mapped is an array of the class with more fields
        }
    }

    [DelimitedRecord(",")]
    public class Orders
    {
        public string Name;

        public string Track;

        public string Price;
    }

    public class MoreFields: Orders
    {
        public string Product;
        public string BasePrice;
        ...
     }
}
```

Comment: hmm..I think this is what I need.  So I iterate through my `customersandproducts` collection to add the information to `MoreFields` class.  Then when the code executes `var mapped = Mapper.Map<Orders[], MoreFields[]>(records );` it's going to map the two data fields to each other?  How does it know to map collections with the CustomerName as the key?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `FieldOptional` attribute for your extra fields. Then they will be ignored for import, but included for export.

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class Orders
{
    public string Name;
    public string Track;
    public string Price;
    [FieldOptional]
    public string Product
    [FieldOptional]
    public string BasePrice
    [FieldOptional]
    public string ShipPrice
    [FieldOptional]
    public string TotalPrice
}
```

Then something like:

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Orders>();
var records = engine.ReadFile("Daniel.csv");
// transform the collection with a foreach loop
foreach(var record in records)
{
   var customer = custs.ByName(record.Name);
   record.Product = etc...
   record.BasePrice = etc...
}
// write out the file including the optional fields.
engine.WriteFile("Daniel_transformed.csv", records);
```